# Need to specify type explicitly when using match type with enum - Scala 3

Tags: scala, types, enums, scala-3, match-types

I'm trying to understand why I need to specify the specific enum type I'm using to be able to use the "match type" feature of scala 3.

```
val doesntCompile: String = testTypeMatch(FieldType.Text)
val compile: String = testTypeMatch[FieldType.Text.type](FieldType.Text)

def testTypeMatch[T <: FieldType](fieldType: T): Elem[T] =
  fieldType match
    case _: FieldType.Text.type   => "randomString"
    case _: FieldType.Number.type => 55

type Elem[x <: FieldType] = x match
  case FieldType.Text.type   => String
  case FieldType.Number.type => Int

enum FieldType {
  case Text
  case Number
}
```

Without hardcoding [FieldType.Text.type] I'm getting a compilation error.

I've tried the same with sealed trait and it worked fine, specifying the type was not needed

```
sealed trait FieldType
object FieldType{
  case object Text extends FieldType
  case object Number extends FieldType
}
```

Comment: Answering this question might be much easier if you'd post the error message of the compilation error that you're getting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inferred type of `FieldType.Text` is `FieldType`, not `FieldType.Text.type`.

Analogously, for the enum

```
enum Foo:
  case Bar
```

the expression `Foo.Bar` will have the type `Foo` by default (try it out in the repl), similarly to how `"hello"` has the type `String` and not the singleton type `"hello"`.

Demoting the `FieldType` to a marker trait solves the issue:

```
val compilesAsExpected: String = testTypeMatch(Text)

def testTypeMatch[T <: FieldType](fieldType: T): Elem[T] =
  fieldType match
    case _: Text.type   => "randomString"
    case _: Number.type => 55

type Elem[x <: FieldType] = x match
  case Text.type   => String
  case Number.type => Int

sealed trait FieldType
object Text extends FieldType
object Number extends FieldType
```

I must admit that I'm not so sure whether this is the most idiomatic way to do it, though; The `enum` keyword was supposed to replace `sealed trait`s, but this seems to be one of those cases where `sealed trait`s behave quite differently from the `enum`s.